# why does readLong method cause EOFException?

Tags: java, io, binary, eof

It throws eof exception in line 10 when I execute the following code. It seems that it cannot execute the readLong method. What should I do?

```
try (DataOutputStream dataOutputStream=new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new 
FileOutputStream("1.dat")));
         DataInputStream dataInputStream=new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new 
FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Asus\\IdeaProjects\\Example" +
                 "\\1.dat")))){
        dataOutputStream.writeLong(123);
        dataOutputStream.writeChar('D');
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Hello!");

        System.out.println(dataInputStream.readLong());//exception occurse here
        System.out.println(dataInputStream.readChar());
        System.out.println(dataInputStream.readUTF());
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug this code? What did you find? Hint: put a breakpoint before reading the file, open the file with a text editor, what do you see?

Comment: I do not know how to debug and I do not understand what happened, but this is the picture:  https://pasteboard.co/KcGzZDY.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you are reading the file before writing on it. when you read the file it was empty. also the data are not saved to the file until the stream is closed. so if you want to read the written values you should close the input stream and then read the file.
also be careful that the output stream file path is different than the input stream

**here an example:**

```
  try ( DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("1.dat")))) {
        dataOutputStream.writeLong(123);
        dataOutputStream.writeChar('D');
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Hello!");
        dataOutputStream.close();
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("1.dat")));
        System.out.println(dataInputStream.readLong());
        System.out.println(dataInputStream.readChar());
        System.out.println(dataInputStream.readUTF());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Closing is not necessary, but flushing the data to ensure they are written to disk is.